# How do I add more than one sheet to Excel file without deleting the other sheets and how to write in 2nd sheet after line 65563 to the end file

Tags: python, xls, xlwt

I have a file with more than 840,000 lines, about 140 columns, and when I want to convert the file from Text file to Excel spreadSheet file, The error looks like this:

```
value error: row index was 65536, not allowed by .xls format
```

As you know, Excel cannot write more than 65,536 rows!

I need to create more than one Excel Sheet, the first sheet contains the 65535 lines, the second sheet completes from 65536 to the maximum extent possible, and I need a lot of Excel spreadSheet to convert all the Text file to Excel spreadsheet.
If there is another way to convert all Text file to Excel with one sheet, I am grateful to you.

note: If running the code on a small file, it was processed correctly without errors.

Convert text file to Excel spreadsheet, Or create more than Excel Sheet and convert the Text file by dividing it on more than one sheet.

```
import xlwt
import io
book = xlwt.Workbook()
ws = book.add_sheet('First Sheet')  # Add a sheet

with io.open("test.txt", mode="r", encoding="utf-8") as f:

     for row_idx, row in enumerate(f):
     row = row.rstrip()
     ws.write(row_idx, 0, row[0:8])
     .
     .
     .
     .
book.save("exceltest.xls")
```

Comment: XLS can't do over 65536 rows..XLSX can hold your entire file in one sheet

Comment: @Derek Eden , thx, I tried to write it in both ways"xls" and "xx" , but the same Error, unfortunately, do you have a solution in another way?

Comment: @Laurent LAPORTE, please, Can you solve this problem?

Comment: xlwt doesn't save to xlsx though...you're just changing the extension at the end of writing...with the amount of code you have here and the sample code for openpyxl it's like 15min of work to redo what you've done to avoid this entire issue

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a new sheet once every 65535 rows.

something like:

```
import xlwt
import io
book = xlwt.Workbook()
sheetnumber = 0

with io.open("test.txt", mode="r", encoding="utf-8") as f:

     for row_idx, row in enumerate(f):
        if row_idx % 65535 = 0:
            sheetnumber += 1
            ws = book.add_sheet('Sheet ' + sheetnumber)  # Add a sheet

        row = row.rstrip()
        ws.write(row_idx, 0, row[0:8])
        .
        .
        .
        .
book.save("exceltest.xls")
```

Comment: thx , This error appears : syntax error: if row_idx % 65535 = 0 ?!

Comment: should be == not =

Comment: @DerekEden, thx, I modified it but shows another error which is identification error : unexpected indent.           row = row.rstrip()

Comment: have to fix the indentation